# Can I create sub domain for each user in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want users create their own account and users should get their own like user.foo.com and different point to different template folder. Is it possible in Django. I quite new to Django

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django itself is unaware of whatever web server you are using.  Usually, to configure extra sub-domains, you need to add virtual hosts to your webserver's configuration and make sure your DNS provider forwards requests for that sub-domain to the appropriate server.

To do this directly, you'll need to run Django under a user account that has write access to your webserver's configuration file, which is **really** not recommended.  Assuming all the hosts are on the same machine, you could do this indirectly, such as queuing requests and have someone manually approve them and edit the file, or have a script run through `cron` and re-write the server configuration every X minutes/hours/days.

Also, DNS registration is a major issue.  If you have a wildcard domain name such as `"*.foo.com"`, you'll be fine.  If your DNS provider doesn't allow this, you'll need to have someone register the extra sub-domains manually.

Basically, almost none this is related to Django, and almost all of it depends on your server's software stack (which you have not specified).

Answer (score 14):

The answer provided by Andre isn't exactly correct.  You will indeed need a wildcard domain, most decent providers will allow this including GoDaddy (IE this is not a limitation you should be terribly concerned with).

"To do this directly, you'll need to run Django under a user account that has write access to your webserver's configuration file, which is really not recommended. Assuming all the hosts are on the same machine, you could do this indirectly, such as queuing requests and have someone manually approve them and edit the file, or have a script run through cron and re-write the server configuration every X minutes/hours/days."

This is completely wrong in basically every way.  In fact all you need to pull this off is this:[Subdomain Middleware](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/).  Simply couple that with an appropriate webserver config to accept requests to *.example.com and you have the necessary variable to take your queue off of in every view

Comment: Except that there are obvious limitations with this.  With this solution, all users will share data in the same database, run under the same user account, all users have the same apps (therefore the same settings).  The last one basically means you can't have other sub-domains not tied to user accounts, such as `www.foo.com`.

Comment: still +1'd your answer, as it is an alternate solution.

Comment: Is there a refreshed/better answer to this question since 2011?

Comment: This is the real answer, not the one above.

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is the Django Tenant Architecture which is done well using Postgresql if that is not a limitation for you. There are 3 available configurations :-

1. Single Database for all.
2. Single Database, Different Schema Tables for all
3. Different databases for each customer or tenant.

For now, I will go ahead with the second approach.

What it does is it creates different database schemas.

After Installing Postgresql and the necessary db connectors and drivers, change the settings in Database and then install this app: https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html -

```
pip install django-tenant-schemas
```

Add:-

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend',
    # ..
}
```

}

Then proceed to add this line.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = (
'tenant_schemas.routers.TenantSyncRouter',
```

)

This installs the tenant schemas.

Which means it gives Django the cognition to differentiate a tenant.

After which adding the middleware class to the top of Middleware stack ensures Tenants have the first filter.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'tenant_schemas.middleware.TenantMiddleware',
#...
```

)

Once you have configured this, define Tenant Model i.e. the Table that will hold info of different subdomains and users so each user's data is isolated.

Then define Public/Shared  apps, that all users will have the same access to and then Tenant Specific apps which will hold only their data i.e. their tenant specific data.

```
SHARED_APPS = (
'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app
'customers', # you must list the app where your tenant model resides in

'django.contrib.contenttypes',

# everything below here is optional
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

)

TENANT_APPS = (
'django.contrib.contenttypes',

```
# your tenant-specific apps
'myapp.hotels',
'myapp.houses',
```

)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'tenant_schemas',  # mandatory, should always be before any django app

```
'customers',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.admin',
'myapp.hotels',
'myapp.houses',
```

)

Set your tenant Model

Eg:-

TENANT_MODEL = "customers.Client" # app.Model

Then do the makemigrations for the app that holds the Client/Tenant table.

Then :-

```
python manage.py migrate_schemas --shared
```

This will create the schemas and set you up to allow different tenants and different databases for each tenants which by default will be segregated by subdomain of a domain you set in the Client/Tenant App.