# How to create sub domains in django and redirect each sub domain to some vanity domain like abc.mydomain.com--> www.yourdomain.com?

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, redirect, django-middleware

I am trying to create a multi tenant site using django.So the basic idea is when ever a user fills all the details I want to redirect the user from mydomai.com/xyz to user.mydomain.com and if the user has a domain registered then I want to redirect the subdomain to that domain name. How can I implement the same using django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

There is more on 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#django-views-generic-simple-redirect-to

Comment: How will i create sub-domains in the first place to redirect to?

Comment: or this might explain you better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543145/can-i-create-sub-domain-for-each-user-in-django